# declare an array in a for

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a method for declare and use an array in a `for` loop like this:

```
foreach(string j in ["1","1"])
{

}
```

?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (string j in new string[] {"1","1"})
{

}
```

Comment: Eric Lippert has talked on his blog about a potential new feature allowing you to just use {"1","1"}, and then type would be inferred as a string collection of some type.  But who knows if it'll go anywhere.

Comment: @Joel: I wouldn't hold my breath in anticipation while waiting. Note that you can elide either or both "string"s in this case and type inference will figure it out. "foreach(var j in new[] {"1","1"})" is good.

Answer (score 1):

The intent escapes me, but yes:

```
foreach(var j in new[] { "1", "1" })
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The cleanest way I can think of is:

```
foreach (char c in "11")
{

}
```

This assumes you only want single letters of course.

Comment: Please give an explanation to downvote PLEASE! Unconstructive people on this site is really pissing me off.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would imagine it's because you aren't declaring an array, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Good point, I just assumed he didn't actually want the array but the iterating over its elements. Whatever, at least somebody said something...